# Javascript function call from Jade template is not Working

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I want to call javascript function from my JADE template. I tried solutions posted in forum. but still it gives me error like "undefined is not a function"

My Javascript function is

```
 script.
   function addCommas(nStr) {
               return nStr;
       }
```

And i am calling this function from JADE template like -

```
 td(style='width: 10%;') #{addCommas("12345")}
```

But i throws error as below -

```
undefined is not a function
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: your function should be available before you use it. undefined is not a function means function is not available yet.

Comment: @atinder - Yes. that's right. but i have written my function under script tag only and its javascript function. can you please suggest anything that i need to try to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

This template code adds a function to call in javascript on the client side:

```
  script.
      function addCommas(nStr) { return nStr; }
```

But this template code call a function on the server side but they undefined (according to the previous):

```
td(style='width: 10%;') #{addCommas("12345")}
```

So, if you want define and call fuction on the server side you need define a template for another her:

```
- function addCommas(nStr) { return nStr; }
```

If you want to call this function on the client side, then leave it in the same definition, but it causes so for example:

```
script.
  console.log( addCommas("12345") );
```

Comment: I want to call javascript (client side) function. not server side. so you mean i can call client side function with #{addCommas("12345")} ? Please suggest correct way for this.

Comment: No, this notation is the function call on the server side at the time when the template is rendered: `#{addCommas("12345")}`. And the result of the execution will be added to the place of function calls.

Comment: Oh..That's sounds perfect. Thanks @stdob-- My issue solved. i have declared my function as a server side just under scope of jade.